# How can I output soft label predictions from RandomForestClassifier instead of 0 or 1's

Tags: random-forest, kaggle

I'm doing a kaggle competition with binary classification. I want to output the probabilistic outputs (soft labels- some value between 0 and 1) rather than just 0 and 1. Not sure how to output my predictions like this though? Using randomforestclassifier

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `predict_proba(X)` of the model.

This function predicts the class probabilities for an X.

The documentation says:

> The predicted class probabilities of an input sample are computed as
> the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest. The
> class probability of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the
> same class in a leaf.

So, imagine that your RandomForest is formed for 100 different trees. If 91 of these trees predict that the sample is class 0, and 9 trees predicts it's class 1, the output of `predict_proba(X)` will be:

```
[0.91, 0.09]
```

Whereas if you use predict(X), you will obtain directly the class prediction (in this case, class 0 since 0.91 is bigger than 0.09):

```
[0]  # Which refers to class 0
```